# Redirect aspx page to another

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

**Windows Server 2008 R2.**

I've installed URL Rewrite on my server. I'm having difficulties with redirecting one page to another within the same site e.g.

I would like to redirect

```
www.mysite.com/content/old/content.aspx
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/content/new/content.aspx?id=1&sid=2
```

I've tried a few way to accomplish this but is proving to be more difficult than i thought. How could i redirect just one page?

I've tried

```
  <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="Web.RewriteMaps.config"/>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Old Page Redirects" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*"/>
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{OldPages:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

within my config file i have

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="OldPages">
    <add key="/content/old/content.aspx" value="/content/new/content.aspx?id=1&sid=2" />
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Comment: as per your statement "I've tried a few way to" _what have you tried_ should be added in question.

Comment: Judging by your response it seems there maybe more than one way of accomplishing this? I tried to create a blank rule and selecting options what i thought were relevant i.e. requested URL = Matches the pattern, Using the exact match (but either got an error or i wasnt able to save). Could you advise what way you are thinking would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found how it should be done.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect single page" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="old.aspx" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="URL/page.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Response.Redirect("www.mysite.com/content/new/content.aspx?id=1&sid=2");`

Write this code inside any events you want to use.

eg :

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Response.Redirect("www.mysite.com/content/new/content.aspx?id=1&sid=2");
   }
```

We can also use javascript for navigation.

```
window.location = "window.location = "SomePage.aspx";
```

Comment: I wont be able to do that as i dont have access to the code behind file. Was hoping to do this within IIS

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/09/18/how-to-redirect-a-url-in-iis6-iis7-and-in-asp-net.aspx Please go through this link.

Comment: I saw that link to but it was redirecting a directory to a page and not a page to a page (unless i missed something?)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to add something like this into the web.config of your asp.net app (which will allow dynamic pages:

```
 <system.webServer>
 <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="www.mysite.com/content/new/content.aspx?id=1&sid=2" />
```

I'm not sure about this. Since I got this from this site itself. please try this too.

Comment: I think that redirects the entire site? I only require one page